# How to remove a class once reaching the bottom of page

Tags: jquery, if-statement, addclass, removeclass

I have a working script which adds the class of "stick" when the div reaches the top of the page so that it remains visible at the top of the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var s = $("#side-div");
var pos = s.position();                    
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop() ;

    if (windowpos >= 670) {
        s.addClass("stick");
    } 

    else if ($("body").height() <= ($(window).height() + windowpos)) {

         s.removeClass("stick");    

    }
    else {
        s.removeClass("stick"); 
    }
});
```

});

That part works.  However, I am trying to "unstick" this div once it reaches the bottom of the page.  Actually, I am trying to un-stick it when the footer becomes visible. But I have not even been able to get to that part.

I do realize that there are plugins out there that I can use.

http://viget.com/inspire/jquery-stick-em

However, I am trying to achieve this effect w/o using any plugin.  I am actually trying to learn how to script jQuery more than anything else.

If I were interested in solving my problem, using the plugin would be simple & easy.  But I am trying to learn why my else if part does not work.

Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing okay, there's just a problem with your if else statements and conditions. If you put this on top `if (windowpos >= 670) {`, even if you reached the bottom this condition remains true and will still be executed.

I also see you included a `var pos = s.position();` but never really used it, so I think what you may be trying to do is to set sticky if you reached the `$("#side-div")`'s position.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $("#side-div");
    var pos = s.offset().top;  

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop() ;

        if(windowpos + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){
            s.removeClass('stick');
        }else if(windowpos >= pos){
            s.addClass('stick');
        }else{
            s.removeClass('stick');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/KHAce/)

Comment: oh, thanks!!  I did not see your reply.  I actually figured out a better way to achieve what I wanted to accomplish as you can see here:

http://hackya.com/us

But thank you for your solution nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

set minus instead of plus... you will see the blue color which id in my example under the "else" statement.

working fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/4YaPw/**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var pos = $("#side-div").position();     
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (windowpos >= 670)
        {
            $("#side-div").css('background-color', '#8a7b70'); //grey
        } 

        else if ($("body").height() <= ($(window).height() - windowpos))
        {
            $("#side-div").css('background-color', '#ff5400'); //orange
        }
        else
        {
            $("#side-div").css('background-color', '#6f8cc0'); //blue
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: shukran, Hasan!!

damn, I see what I was doing wrong now.

Again, thank you very much.

Comment: @Matthew I'm not Arabic, I'm Turkish, but it's fine, glad to help :)

Comment: Oh.. sorry.  um... I am also having trouble selecting your reply as my answer.  I am not seeing the damn button/option to pick your reply as my answer.

Comment: actually, that didn't help. XD

In you jsfiddle example, the color doesn't change to orange.

My div still stays stick & fails to un-stick when scrolled down to the bottom of the page.

Comment: It's because the first if statement condition is `if (windowpos >= 670)`, even when you reached the bottom this condition is still true and will continue to execute.